# CSS3 not transitioning ease-out with CSS Circular Progress Bars

Tags: css

My transition, well, doesn't transition.

https://gist.github.com/TadahTech/0915cd6fc22fa27a94a4

I am completely unsure why there isn't a transition happening, but I assume it's a 
simple answer. I've been staring at this for too long and was hoping for some fresh eyes on the issue.

```
section.progress-container {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    position: relative;;
}

circle#empty {
    stroke: #EDEDED;
    stroke-width: 2em;
}

circle#percent-loaded {
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1.6 ease-in;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2em;
}
```

The JS

```
$(function() {

  calculateProgress = function(percentLoaded) {
    var $percentLoadedCircle = $("circle#percent-loaded");

    var radius = $percentLoadedCircle.attr("r");

    var circumference = Math.PI * (radius * 2);

    var arcPercent = ((100 * percentLoaded) / 100);

    var arcLengthOffset = arcPercent * circumference;

    $percentLoadedCircle.css({
      strokeDashoffset: arcLengthOffset
    });
  }
  calculateProgress(100);
});
```

Index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Countdown Test Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="progress-container">
        <svg height="240" width="240" viewport="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle id="empty" r="100" cx="120" cy="120" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
            <circle id="percent-loaded" r="100" cx="120" cy="120" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
        </svg>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the code you need help with to your question.

Comment: Odd, I thought I did, either way, there now.

Comment: The problem is `transition: stroke-dashoffset 1.6 ease-in;`. You haven't specified a time unit (s or ms etc) for the time. So browsers would treat that as wrong property value and ignore it. If you add the time units, it works perfectly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jaL1awg7/
This is what happens with a time unit attached.